# Is a special library or import needed for ImageUtil to work?

Tags: java, image

I am new to Java and I am trying to learn images from several tutorials. 
I have found many uses of ***ImageUtil***.something but when I try to use this in my code it always gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
ImageUtil cannot be resolved
ImageUtil cannot be resolved
at spriteAnimation.Animation.main(Animation.java:35)
```

line 35: `BufferedImage img = ImageUtil.makeColorTransparent(`

Here are the imports I am using if it will help answer the question:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

also tried:

```
    import java.util.*;
```

---

Here is the code I am using:

```
// Init the resources
    BufferedImage img = ImageUtil.makeColorTransparent(
            "mario2.png", new Color(0, 115, 0));
    BufferedImage[] imgs = ImageUtil.splitImage(img, 6, 4);
```

Is there a required library or import that needs to be set up for ***ImageUtil*** to work?

Comment: This might be a third party library. What tutorials are you following?

Comment: Looks like a built-in class to be used in the tutorial.

Comment: http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/#12

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza
You were Correct, I had to create that specific class and add the needed methods to that class. Works fine after you mentioned the built-in Class. Thanks +1 for you if it was possible